# How to include plot in html from rmarkdown

Tags: r

I am trying to create a website in r

I want to visualise a circular plot in the generated html which I create using the code below:

````
```{r} 
    #Create data
name=c(3,10,10,3,6,7,8,3,6,1,2,2,6,10,2,3,3,10,4,5,9,10)
feature=paste("feature ", c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5) , sep="")
dat <- data.frame(name,feature)
dat <- with(dat, table(name, feature))

# Charge the circlize library
library(circlize)
# Make the circular plot
chordDiagram(as.data.frame(dat), transparency = 0.5)
````

```

This runs fine in r studion but when i issue:

`rmarkdown::render_site("~My_website")` it crashes RStudio. If I hashtag out the `chordDiagram(...` line then the website renders fine. Is there a problem with adding this plot to html? Do I have to generate a separate figure...surely not?

Comment: It renders fine in a standard Rmarkdown file. Are you talking about R Markdown websites?

Comment: #F.Prive yes it is when I render rmarkdown websites

Comment: You might want to report as a bug at RStudio? You can try to run it from the command line maybe? Otherwise, you can prerender and simply load an image instead, as a workaround.

Comment: Works fine also with R Markdown websites: https://privefl.github.io/test. Try to update all your packages.